Increasing Concrete Wall Height while Repairing a Rotting Sill Plate
Recent new homeowner here, with some big new problems to fix! The house is from 1968 and is in Michigan, so we get precipitation, snow, melting cycles, etc. The first problem we're trying to solve is a rotting sill plate in our garage. I've included pictures along with a cross-section of how the wall is currently built, and an illustration of the changes that I think we need to make.
When we bought the place, the soil was piled up above the siding/sill plate. I don't know how long it was like that, but we moved some serious amounts of soil and you can see daylight in the garage now. Not ideal, though the squirrels in my ceiling seem to love it. There's really no way to lower the soil (and driveway!) as much as it would need to be lowered in order to have the current sill-plate level make sense. So I think we need to add at least one layer of concrete block, and rest a new sill plate on top of that. An 8" tall block would take the top of the concrete wall to 4" above grade, so I think we should add two layers of block, to take it to 12" above grade.
A few complications:

The 4" thick concrete pad is resting halfway on the top of the current concrete block wall and the sill plate is NEXT to the concrete pad. Not on top of. NEXT to. In other words, the concrete block, viewed from above, is 8" wide, and 4" is covered by concrete pad and 4" is covered by a rotting sill plate. So, there's only 4" of space where a concrete block can be set. A 4" wide block seems too unstable, I think - especially if I'm doing two layers of this block. So, I'm thinking of taking a 6"x8"x16" block and cutting out a notch along the length, so that 4" of the block can be stacked directly onto the existing wall and then 2" of the block (the part that's notched out) will rest on the concrete pad. I would tie this block and the block above it to the existing concrete wall with rebar and poured concrete into the block cavities. I'm thinking of using the 6" deep block just to keep it from sticking too far out into the garage. If you think the 8" deep block would be significantly better, please let me know.

There's also a thin form around the concrete pad. I don't know if I would need to remove that, or if I could just adjust my cut accordingly and mortar to the form instead of to the concrete. I'm going to be powerwashing and etching the existing block to improve adhesion.

I don't know I would be able to use a j-hook here, since the studs are already in place. I'm thinking I would need to fill the blocks with concrete, let it set, and then drill a hole in the concrete, attach the sill plate to the studs, and then use a wedge anchor through the sill plate and into that drilled hole in the new concrete.

The sheathing on the wall is some sort of black, fiberboard sheathing. And over that are vertical cedar boards. We're going to cut a few inches off the bottom, to clean up the rotten portions of that, but we don't want to cut it 12" above grade (the top of the new concrete wall). We need some sort of vapor barrier though, right? So, I'm thinking I would cut the fiberboard to around the bottom of the new sill plate, and then slide foam board insulation between the concrete wall and the wood board.

I'm not including a metal termite barrier (not sure how we would do that with the sill plate so high and the wood siding as it is). If you think that's a must have and have an idea of how I could do it, please let me know.

Do you think the rebar into the block below is enough? Any need to drill into the concrete pad and try to tie into that somehow?


Any advice, opinions, or insight is greatly appreciated!







Replacing the wood(sill plate) on the bottom with pressure treated wood might be easier than raising the building enough for more blocks.

some details require location.  primary heating or primary cooling?  seismic zone?

I'd just drypack under the block instead of notching - that seems like way too much work.

A cellular pvc fascia board run horizontally might work well to hide the new block and allow you to cleanup the siding look.

@crip659 it's not quite clear but perhaps the OP doesn't want to raise the whole building, but simply cut out the bottoms of the existing studs to put the concrete block in there?

Thanks for the comments. Regarding location - I'm in Mid Michigan, USA. The current sill plate is 4" under the driveway level (which is the same level as the concrete pad), which is why I'm trying to replace a portion of the wood wall with concrete. With the precipitation/melting we have here, water WILL get in, and eventually PT will meet the same fate, if I do it the same. As Huesmann noted, I am NOT trying to raise the building. I'm planning to shorten the wood portion of the walls - increasing the concrete portion and shortening the wood portion equally, leaving the total height the same.

Someone elsewhere suggested that I use 4x4x16 hollow core block (so that the wall height is now equal to the concrete pad height), and then put the (full) 6x8x16 concrete block on top of that. I would tie those three blocks (the 6x8x16, the 4x4x16, and the existing 8x8x16) together with rebar. That makes sense to me. More logical than notching a block out. So I think that's my current plan. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/guqV1iB
